# How to create window installer for python application with mysql database?

Tags: python, mysql, windows-installer

I have developed a little application with python and PyQt that is connected to a mysql server. During development I started by setting up the mysql server, then developed the interaction functionality with python and lastly built the GUI with PyQt. Now, in order to be able to deploy my application to windows systems I need to create an installer that is not only setting up the software but also the mysql server. However, I am completely lost on how to do that. Can anyone give me a direction on where to go from here?

Best regards

Comment: You don't really want to require users to install a complete MySQL installation.  That's a huge burden.  It would be better to provide a way for users to specify their own MySQL connection string, with instructions on how to set one up if they don't have access to one, or maybe even use sqlite3, which is built-in with Python.

Comment: Hm, maybe I'll have to move to sqlite then, because I want to make the setup as user friendly as possible. My only worry with that is the limitations of multiple connections in sqlite.